# configure awscli and ecr login for kubernetes cluster on bare metal

Tags: kubernetes, aws-cli, amazon-ecr, bare-metal-server

I have done a kubernetes bare metal deployment. In which I have to go to every worker-node and configure awscli and ECR login. Can we have solution using kubernetes where we can get the aws configure for all the worker node and login ecr .

Comment: What deployment tool did you use? Usually you would do it through that tool.

Comment: I used kubeadm for cluster deployment.

Comment: That’s not really a full tool. It’s just an automation layer. Check out kubespray instead.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is [`--cloud-provider=aws`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#kubeadm) and its `--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/cloud.conf` friend; when those are passed into `kube-apiserver`, `kube-controller-manager`, and `kubelet`, they will configure themselves to be able to authenticate to ECR, provided the [Node's IAM Instance Profile](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws#iam-policy) allows it

*Be careful:* you'll see a lot of noise about `--cloud-provider=external` and running the `cloud-provider-aws` outside of `kube-controller-manager`, but [that story is not as happy shiny as they make it seem](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws/issues/42) and I personally have yet to make `cloud-provider=external` work correctly whereas setting `--cloud-provider=aws` works perfectly

Comment: that will be fine for an ec2 , but I'm doing the deployment on bare-metal non-ec2.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant the bare metal ec2 instance types; sorry about that. Hmm, that's tougher, since I actually don't recall ever having seen a place to specify AWS credentials but it seems plausible there is such a place and I've just never seen it